# unable to watch expressions in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, debugging

I have a Maven project which is cloned from Git. Project was successfully built and runs perfectly. However when i debug and try to evaluate functions/expressions, it gives me error saying --

```
expression must be compiled in the context of a Java Project's build path.
```

I read previous stack overflow answers and did the following (with no results)--

1. I added java nature to .project file and then added Java Project in source lookup. Still i get same error.
2. If i remove the Java project from source lookup and choose option --"Workspace folder" while adding Source lookup path, it gives me Null Pointer exception.

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

Try this !!!

```
Find the thread in your debug window that you are in the breakpoint for. Right click on it. Under relaunch should be an edit launch configuration selection. Select that.

Select Source tab. Add. Java Project. Select the java project that the code exists in.
```

Comment: I already tried that (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988117/eclipse-inspectctrlshifti-not-working).
1. I need to change nature of my project to Java nature. Only then the project becomes visible
2. Even if i change the nature, this does not help. I get the same error

Comment: have you tried this `Right click on the project ->build path -> select source tab -> add folder` and then added the folder which contains the java classes.